# Is there a known place for gathering all my public profiles in a single place in the Web?

Tags: profile

I have many accounts with public profiles in different web-services. They are, for example, linkedin.com, coursera.org, bitbucket.org, projecteuler.org, dropbox.com and etc. Unfortunately, not all of them support the OpenID technology.

What is the best known method to gather all of those profiles in a single place in the Web to take advantage of easy sharing?

Comment: @phwd I suppose this question is not off topic. This question is covered with "any other website which behaves like an application" properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could list and link them all in the profiles of one of a social network, or use a service like [about.me](http://about.me), or on a page on your website or blog.

**Edit** - A quick search shows that [Flavors.me](http://flavors.me/) might be a good site for this. From their home page -

> ## Pull Everything Together
>
> Automatically organizes content from 35 services – more than anywhere else – into an elegant and cohesive online presence.

Comment: About.me is the case. I have not known about this, thanks :)